# How to debug an Outlook web add-in?

Tags: debugging, outlook, outlook-addin

### Standing offer

It looks like my bounty is about to expire, with nary an answer.

If anyone can answer this in future, I will award a bounty. If I find out how, I will post an answer.

---

I am struggling to even begin developing my first Outlook web add-in.

Ideally, I want to add an icon to the main toolbar and, when clicked, I want it to pop up a dialog (which will be an HTML page running an existing Angular JS app).

I already have the icon on the main toolbar (desktop client only, as outlook.office.com does not have a toolbar, and it looks like `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` should pop up an HTML page as a dialog.

I see no pop-up when clicking the icon, but am stymied as to how to debug such an add-in from the Outlook desktop client. Can anyone tell me how?

I was thinking of switching to web based email for development, but

1) I won't have a main toolbar, and would have to temporarily move my icon, and

2), I tried that before,  but couldn't the output of `console.log()` or `alert()`, even as the first statement of my Angular JS controller. Is there some other/better way to debug a web-based app?

I have Googled, but there is a paucity of information. How can I develop such an add-in and debug it?

---

[Update] See my answer below. It's simple

Comment: Why the downvote? If you know the answer, please help - that it what this site is for. It may seem simple to you, but I have been Googling & trying things on & off for months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provides detailed documentation regarding many things and many other sources often reference them, although you have probably been through these I'm just linking them here in case.

If you are using an **attached debugger from the task pane**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane

If you are using **F12 developer tools on Windows 10**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: I will remove this from your thread if you have already thoroughly been through these, or keep them on to help with others having a similar problem. This will be at your discretion.

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 Jared. I thought that I had been through all of the docs, but that seems new - and very useful

Comment: If I can figure out how to increase the bounty, I will :-)

Comment: @Mawg No problem, so glad I could help

Comment: Alas, in the end I could get neither of these to work with Outlook :-(

Answer (score 8):

Despite accepting Jared's answer, I couldn't get actually get it to work in the end.

I did, however, find a solution, and post it here to help others.

It was blindingly simple; I use [Office 365 Outlok](https://outlook.office.com/owa/), rather than the desktop version.

Just press F12 for the browser's developer console, switch to the "Debugger" tab, look for - in my case - `localhost`, and there are my files, which I can debug as with any other web app.

I don't know why I was stuck for weeks with this - just a blind spot, I guess.  Hope this helps someone :-)

[image]

Comment: This is really underrated, and super useful. Thanks.

Comment: But how to debug the add-in in the software, not on the online website?

Comment: The screen shot shows my add-in being debugged, on localhost. What else are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Look like the [F12 development tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) will work natively as well. I'm on a Windows 10 vm and need to manually launch via command line.

** For 32-bit:
`C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe`

**  For 64-bit:
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe`

Comment: Does it work also for Outlook 365? (I'm not sure they run internally the IE anymore, maybe Edge?)

Answer (score 1):

I am reasonably sure that this is now impossible - Microsoft have migrated away from "EdgeHtml" to "EdgeChrome" so all the debug facilities for Office Add-Ins that used to work before this year are no longer functional.

The unresolved issue on the project github page suggests it's been broken since about May 2021:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/vscode-debugger-extension-for-office-addins/issues

Ironic that MS don't seem to be maintaining their tools, given the AppSource hard-requirement that we keep all *our* apps maintained :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for that information (+1). I had abandoned this project, but would love to restart it again - ***if*** I could debug it. If you ever find out how, please post an answer here & I will award you bonus points.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who cannot get regular debugging to work, for whatever reason, here's 2 work-arounds I'm using which so-far are at least "ok".

1. If you're developing a task-pan add-in, put a  in your task pane, and write your debug output into that pane:-

Put this in the taskpane.html:-

```
    <textarea id="out" rows=10 cols=46>debug info here</textarea>
```

And put this in the taskpane.js:-

```
try {
  // your code
} catch (error) {
  document.getElementById("out").value += "error:" + error;
}
```

2. For any other (including task pane) things you're doing, you can also send your debug data to a remote server, and then on that remote server you can "tail" the output:-

Put this in the commands.js:-

```
function eLog(yourUrl){
  var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);//nb: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Httpreq.send(null);
  return Httpreq.responseText;
}
```

Then you can log your errors by adding the logging text into the URL GET query_string like this:

```
try {
  // your code
} catch (error) {
  eLog("https://www.yourwebsite.com/yourlogscript.cgi?yournotes=here&error="+ JSON.stringify(error)) ;
}
```

You will need to add https://www.yourwebsite.com/ into your manifest.xml (and it must be SSL):

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://www.yourwebsite.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

And your website should return the CORS header:-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

(you don't have to - your server gets the data regardless, but without that header, it raises a JS error which might cause more problems?)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I will dig out my old project & try this (+1).

Comment: Here''s a 100 point bonus, with thanks. For a new guy, you have been a great help. I hope that we will see a lot of you round here in future.